# Is it possible to create a managed package containing Integration procedures, flex cards, dataRaptors?

Tags: managed-package, package, 2gp, unmanaged-package, 1gp-package

We have development that contains flex cards, omniscripts, integration procedures and some dataRaptos. When I want to create a 1GP package I can't find these components and I don't know if it is possible to package this with 2GP packages. Perhaps there is another tool that is responsible for packaging developments of this type. I would like to know if anyone recommends this tool or if you have any other advice.

Answer (score 0):

They are not available for managed 1GP or 2GP package. You could check which metadata is available for which api/tool on [Metadata Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/59) page: type "omni" in quick search box and you'll see that almost every *Omni** metadata can be added just to an unlocked package.

Every time you have such doubts, you could also check [Components Available in Managed Packages page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm), that holds a list of every metadata component that you include in a managed 1GP or 2GP package

Comment: @Nelson An unlocked package is fine if you want to deploy those components in another org. While if you have to create a solution for app-exchange, it must be a managed package, so you cannot add those components, but you can have whatever it needs to expose a business logic (i.e. some flow, apex classes, lwc, etc...), than create an unlocked package that depends upon the managed one, so whoever wants to install the unlocked package must have the managekd one too.

Comment: oh I understand, if you are so kind, can you give me a link that explains how to create an unlocked package that contains this type of component? Later I will see a solution to make these two packages dependent on each other.

Comment: @Nelson Here you go: [Create and Upload an Unmanaged Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading_unmanaged.htm)

Comment: Items like DataRaptors, IntegrationProcedures, Flexcard do not appear in the list of items to add to the package. Even if it is unlocked or unmanage.
https://imgur.com/rVBeEmA
https://imgur.com/gYQsz7E

Comment: @NelsonSA did you search for "OmniDataTransform", "OmniIntegrationProcedure" and "OmniUiCard"?

Comment: https://imgur.com/7Pv4Ocg
In the image you can see the Omni type elements that exist within the list. These are the only Omni-type items on the list. and they have nothing inside.

Comment: @NelsonSA are [Omnistudio Metadata](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_enable_omnistudio_metadata_api_support.htm&type=5) enabled?

Comment: Yes i have enable Omnistudio Metadata